# Bootstrap Year Calendar -Seleccionar Rango de fecha

Tags: javascript, html, html5, bootstrap

Estoy utilizando Year Calendar de bootstrap, y quisiera seleccionar un rango de fecha que puede ir de 1 año a otro, al pasar de un año a otro se pierde la releccion realizada en el año anterior. ¿alguien tiene idea de como hacerlo?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: Hola, puedes mostrarnos tu código fuente para revisarlo y darte una mejor respuesta

Comment: como tal no tengo un codigo para esa selección por eso pregunte si tenian ideas.